# CLI program not doing anything and ignoring my code

Tags: node.js, typescript, command-line-interface

I'm making a sort of programming language for a project with NodeJS and TypeScript, and it's not doing anything that I want it to do. Here is absolutely all of the code:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const cl = require("chalk");

var args = process.argv.slice(2);
if (args.length !== 1) {
    console.log("Error: Only argument should be filename");
} else {
    if (!args[0].endsWith(".qu")) {
        console.log("Error: File provided is not a Quantum file (*.qu)");
    } else {
        if (fs.existsSync(args[0])) {
            var contents = fs.readFileSync(args[0], 'utf8');
            contents = contents.replace(/\r/g, "").split("\n");
            var lineNumber = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i++; i < contents.length) {
                var line = contents[i];
                lineNumber++;
                if (line.startsWith("printLn")) {
                    line = line.replace("printLn", "");
                    if (line.startsWith("(\"")) {
                        line = line.replace("(\"", "");
                        if (line.endsWith("\")")) {
                            line = line.substring(line.length - 2, line.length);
                            console.log(line);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (line == "") {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    console.log(cl.red(`Syntax error at line ${lineNumber}`));
                    console.log(`\t» ${line}`);
                    var date = new Date();
                    var time = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
                    console.log(cl.red(`File ${args[0]} at ${time}`));
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Error: File '" + args[0] + "' does not exist!");
        }
    }
}
```

I have a file called `file.qu` and this is its contents:

```
printLn("Hello!")
random text - should result in error
```

When I type

```sh
node . file.qu
```

Nothing happens! I was expecting this:

```
Hello!
Syntax error at line 2
    » random text - should result in error
File 'file.qu' at [current time]
```

Please tell me what is wrong!

Comment: Did you try to output `args` to console to check what you got there?

Comment: Instead of `node . file.qu`, could you use the name of file pasted above, such as `node index.js file.qu`